# Detect outlier curves

Tags: r, outliers, fitting, growth-model

I'm fitting a population growth model (Monod's model with one extension) with R package FME.

My data is a series of growth curves, with several replicates for different initial concentrations. I have a estimation of the error in each measure (one estimation for each replicate for each time-point) that I'm using for the weight part of modCost.

However, I realized that I have outliers, and I think they are preventing me of doing a correct parameter estimation.

I have two types of outliers. The first is the common type. A curve is fitted very well except for an out of line point. Any advice on how to deal with it inside FME framework?

The complicated case is the second case. Some replicates behave differently. More specifically, just by looking at them them seem to obey to a different set of parameters than the remaining replicates. Reality is always more complicated than models. However, I have no idea how to deal with them. I would like to be able to automatic recognize them and decrease them weight or remove them completely, in order to get a good description of the most common behaviour (without removal I get an average behaviour, which means that it does not fit well either - the common or the outliers). If possible, give you suggestions with R FME package framework in mind.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2013.856795?journalCode=uasa20) article. It is a fairly growing area of statistics.